# Joomla(easy/hard) - homepage working - all other pages give a 404

Tags: html, configuration, joomla, content-management-system

This is the site

http://tinyurl.com/7zo87mm

can anyone tell me why only the homepage works?  all other pages return a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

It seems something wrong with your .htaccess file. Have you checked?

Comment: I have the .htaccess configures exactly the same as another website running joomla (except the domain names changed on the rewrite and SEF core sections. i notice when I click on the home menu item the domain appears and /home.   i.e. www.xxx.com.au/home

Comment: Is the server enviroment same?

Comment: ok I just got a clue.  from within the joomla global config I turned off the apache mod_rewrite.  It is working.  But the index.php is there now in the URL!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you defined a RewriteBase in the .htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following instructions outlined [HERE](http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs_on_Apache)

Nutshell version:
If your Joomla is installed in it's own directory and not root:
Open .htaccess in a text editor. Uncomment RewriteBase / (remove the first character, #). If Joomla is installed in its own folder, the enter the Joomla folder name after the backslash. e.g. RewriteBase /yourjoomlafolder.

Log on to your Back-end and open the Global Configuration.
Enable the Search Engine Friendly URLs option and Save.

Enable the Use Apache mod_rewrite/URL rewriting option and Save.

Check if your site works correctly. Your URLs should now look like http://www.example.com/the-­news/1­-latest-­news/1-­welcome-­to­-joomla.

If this option causes errors, please see How to check if mod rewrite is enabled on your server.

If it is not enabled and you have access to the file apache/conf/httpd.conf, open that file and check if the line LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is uncommented. If necessary, uncomment the line and restart the Apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was under global configuration, in the site tab, to the right hand side is an option for "use url rewriting" change that to no and save. My site came right up after that.